# hot plug a node w/ MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

We are evaluating MongoDB with my team and I have a couple questions that I'm sure are answered somewhere on the web but I couldn't find the answers...

1) Can we hot plug a data node in the MongoDB cluster? If we can how difficult is it?
2) It seems like MongoDB works from the HDD, but does it have a caching strategy to avoid hitting the disk w/ every requests? Is the caching strategy configurable?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, you can add members to the replica set on the go.

2) MongoDB uses memory-mapped files. The interval at which the data is flushed to the disk (fsync) can be configured and is 60 seconds by default.

[MongoDB official documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home) should provide you with answers to most of the questions, that might arise during testing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. I'm going to tackle that right away.